# specific page loses authentication in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

If I move specific page after login, I lose my authentication in django.
And I move another page, I get my authentication again without login.

```
def user(request, user_id):
    """
    Display a user

    :param request: request
    :param user_id: user id
    :return: render
    """
    _user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    _groups = _user.groups

    return render(
        request,
        'archive/user/user.html',
        {
            'user': _user,
            'groups': _groups.exclude(privacy='CLOSED'),
        }
    )
```

This is view code with problem.

Comment: How do you know that you loose your authentication in case if you could proceed on site after accessing view above without login ?

Comment: @Andriy I use this code, `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`. That page returns only false, but other pages return true after login.

Comment: Are you sure that correct `user_id` passed to url? because `_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)` could fetch not right user...

Comment: Try to add `RequestContent(request)` to render method, so replace  `render(yourParams)` to `render(yourParams, RequestContent(request))`

Comment: @Andriy, Thank you for reply. I found the problem, it is caused by `'user': _user`. I make template `user` overwrite my user.

Comment: Ohh great. Glad to assist you, at least somehow...

Answer (score 1):

If having class based views you should use **LoginRequiredMixins**.
This will check if the user is authenticated to access the page or not.
If authenticated, then the page gets displayed otherwise you can redirect to the login page again.

- [More about Login Required Mixing](http://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#loginrequiredmixin)

Example :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class home(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    login_url = "/"
    def get(self,request):
        user = request.user
        s = Person.objects.get(pk=user.id)
        return render(request,'chat/home.html',locals())
```

in the above example, **login_url** is where you provide the link of **redirection** if the *user is not authenticated*. Here I have redirected to the root i.e., the login page.
You can define your views like this.

For function-based views, you can use a **login_required decorator**.

You should also use Django sessions for security.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to login too if you want, works like a charm :

```
class Login(View):
    template_name = ['your_app_name/login.html', 'your_app_name/home.html']

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UsersForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name[0],{"form":form,})


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        #if login is succesfull it takes you to home page:
        return render_to_response(self.template_name[1],RequestContext(request))
    else:
        #if is not, takes you to login page again
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:login'))
```